# Unity Combine GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a cellular automaton in Unity, for that I created a cube as a prefab then I spawn the cubes whenever necessary.
This is, as you can probably tell, very slow, thats why I was thinking that combining all individual cubes into one GameObject after each generation would result in better performance.
How can I do this? If thats not possible I'd be very thankfull if you could give me a hint to what would be a better solution for my problem!

Comment: make one empty gameobject, and your cubes children of that game object. Then you spwan that GO and all the children will be spawned along, as they are part of it

Comment: I'll try that, thanks alot!

Comment: It depend of the purpose and the usage. But you can create a [mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) by code and modify it when you add a new cube.